# transform code from OpenGL 2.1 to OpenGL 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, opengl-3

I want to understand this old code and translate it for newest version of OpenGL with using shaders:

```
        if (channel == Alpha) {
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
        } else {
            // replicate color into alpha
            if (GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3) {
                switch (channel) {
                case Red: 
                    glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.5); 
                    break;                
                case Green: 
                    glColor3f(0.5, 1.0, 0.5); 
                    break;
                case Blue: 
                    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 1.0); 
                    break;
                default:
                    // should not happen!
                    assert(0);
                }
            } else {
                // should not happen!
                assert(0);
            }

            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE_ARB);
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB_ARB, GL_DOT3_RGBA_ARB);
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB_ARB, GL_TEXTURE);
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB_ARB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE1_RGB_EXT, GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
            glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB_EXT, GL_SRC_COLOR);
        }
      <draw models>
```

My ideas whats happening:

```
if channe = Alpha
   just replace alpha
else
   // no idea why used glColor3f
   looks like it makes one of the colors 100% bright
   and then in magical 6 glTexEnvi lines it transforms to alpha
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It set's up a normal mapping texture. The channel switch defines, which axis the "normal" vector points to and sets the color accordingly; today you'd use a uniform for that.

The equation the texture environment for the case that the texture does not consist of merely an alpha channel sets something, that looks like the following fragment shader

```
uniform vec3 primary_direction; // instead of primary color
uniform sampler… tex;

in vec2 tex_coord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( dot(primary_direction, texture(tex, tex_coord)), 1);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I did not copied 2 more strings, now add and it has primary color

Comment: What's happening if channel == Alpha?

Comment: @SAKrisT: Then the values of the texture are passed through. Since it's an alpha texture it will most likely just be used for modulating the blend factor. In GLSL it would be `gl_FragColor = vec4(primary_color.rgb, texture(tex, tex_coord).a);`. The OpenGL fixed function pipeline state machine is a convoluted beast.

Comment: Hold on, but dot product returns float, not vec4.

Comment: @SAKrisT: Forget about that comment earlier, I forgot that `vec4` constructor in my code. The register combiner behavior is to replicate the scalar product over all the channels (technically you can split it up between RGB and Alpha channels).